# Javascript/JQuery event when all data on the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

I have this scenario. When page is showing a have loader which is loading. I have ajax calls and I want the loader to hide when all the data is loaded. Is there an event who fires when all the page is loaded? Or any suggestion how to organize this

Comment: There is no event for Ajax calls. You would have to code something for that.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: @epascarello Not quite true. If you knwo how many you have you can count them in https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

Comment: Or use promises and [promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Combination of ajaxStart and ajaxComplete with a counter might work or some kind of "requires" check in ajaxComplete to see if the components you want are loaded - but there's no way to know "*when all the page is loaded*" as you may check for this before starting a new ajax request or you'd need to know what you're loading (so not generic) - how do you know if a specific request is is part of the "loading" process? 
 Better to just code this yourself.

Comment: @mplungjan I was meaning there is nothing out of the box like OP wants. Yes, there is the complete event and other promise stuff, but you are coding it to do things. Without knowing exactly what OP has to wait for it is hard to actually give an answer/solution.

Comment: Thank you i wil try with counting calls

Answer (score -1):

If really asynchronous eg: not set to async false, your AJAX call should be able to execute something as it finishes and succeed or fail. This is how the call actually work. Look into AJAX and callback function. As for the rest it is quite a vague question with no more context or code example.